# Preserve empty blank lines after loading string into XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have these rather large strings that contain several linebreaks "\r\n" and, in some occasions I may even have sequences of linebreaks "\r\n\r\n...". This results in empty lines, which I do want to preserve upon loading the string into a **XmlDocument** object via `LoadXml()`.

By default, empty lines are removed.

I've managed to find a way to keep those blank lines by using **XDocument**, but I still want to check if there is a way to do that with **XmlDocument** exclusively (so as to avoid to refactor big chunks of my code that rely in **XmlDocument**)

Comment: First line of [remark](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=net-8.0#remarks) Says it does not preserve whitespaces by default

Comment: It's not clear whether we are talking about whitespace occurring between tags (that is, text nodes consisting entirely of whitespace) or about whitespace occuring within text nodes that also contain printable characters.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `XmlDocument.PreserveWhitespace` Property

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace?view=net-8.0

> If `PreserveWhitespace` is `true` before [Load](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.load?view=net-8.0) or [LoadXml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=net-8.0) is called, white space nodes are preserved; otherwise, if this property is false, significant white space is preserved, white space is not.